# Как настроить proxy в selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

Как прописать логин и пароль для подключения к прокси серверу?

У меня пока подключение работает:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://ip:порт");


WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(option);
webDriver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

и может кто знает как избавиться от ошибки при подключение в хроме ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: Про `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` наверное стоит отдельный вопрос задать.

Comment: Автор, как вы там, не решили задачу? Если решили, опубликуйте ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я изменил прокси, чтобы прокси зависило от ip и получилось что логин и пароль не надо вводить

Comment: Отлично. Но лучше не комментарием, а ответом. Ниже на этой странице есть кнопка.